# Query to verify anti-cheat system

Tags: mysql

I have a table that basically collects votes for a specific user:

```
ID | user_id | ip | timestamp
```

Every time someone votes for a user, an entry is created logging the user_id they voted for, their IP address and the time and date.
To prevent cheating we don't allow more than 20 votes per user per IP per day.

Now I'd like to verify these votes, starting from a given date and I've come up with the following query myself but I'm by no means an expert so if anyone could tell me if I have this correct I would greatly appreciate it.

```
SELECT count(*) As `votes`, user_id, ip, DATE( timestamp ) the_date
FROM `user_votes`
GROUP BY user_id, ip, the_date
HAVING the_date > '2012-07-26'
ORDER BY the_date ASC, user_id ASC, votes DESC
```

Comment: I would do count(user_id) instead of count(\*). count(\*) could trigger some performance problems if you have a lot of data

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT count(*) As `votes`, user_id, ip, DATE( timestamp ) the_date
FROM `user_votes`
where the_date > '2012-07-26'
GROUP BY user_id, ip, DATE( timestamp )
having count(*)>20 
ORDER BY DATE( timestamp ) ASC, user_id ASC, votes DESC
```

having count(*)>20 will give you counts more than 20

Answer (score 0):

To get users having valid number of votes you can try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) As `votes`, user_id, ip, DATE( timestamp ) the_date
FROM `user_votes`
WHERE DATE(timestamp ) > '2012-07-26'
GROUP BY user_id, ip, the_date
HAVING COUNT(*) <= 20
ORDER BY the_date ASC, user_id ASC, votes DESC;
```